# How do I get multiple OID values in PySNMP?

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp

I am using `pysnmp` installed by the [`pysnmp-lextudio`](https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp). I chose this package because it is pure Python and thus cross-platform. Other libraries were either too hard for me to understand or not cross-platform or required external system dependencies to be installed.

Currently, I am talking to a [CyberPower PDU](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/products/pdu/), which is basically a power supply with controllable outlets, with the following `get_data` command:

```py
def get_data(ip_address: str, object_identity: str) -> int | str:
    """Get the OID's value. Only integer and string values are currently supported."""
    iterator = getCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData("public", mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget(transportAddr=(ip_address, 161), timeout=1, retries=0),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(object_identity)),
    )

    error_indication, error_status, error_index, variable_bindings = next(iterator)

    if error_indication:
        raise RuntimeError(str(error_indication))
    elif error_status:
        raise RuntimeError(str(error_status))
    else:
        [variable_binding] = variable_bindings
        [_oid, value] = variable_binding
        return convert_snmp_type_to_python_type(value)
```

For a 16-port PDU, calling `get_data` 16 times takes a little over a second. Each call of `get_data` takes around 70ms. This is problematic because it makes keeping a GUI responsive to the actual state of an outlet difficult. I want a sub-process effectively looping at a cadence of 1 Hz to 2 Hz getting the state of all the outlets. This is because an outlet could be turned off or on by something external to the GUI, so it needs to be able to accurately show the actual state.

So I tried adjusting my command to something like this:

```py
def get_multiple_data(ip_address: str, object_identities: list[str]) -> int | str:
    """Get the OID's value. Only integer and string values are currently supported."""
    # The OID for retrieving an outlet's state is hardcoded for debugging purposes
    ids = [".1.3.6.1.4.1.3808.1.1.3.3.5.1.1.4.{}".format(outlet) for outlet in range(1, 17)]
    oids = [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(id)) for id in ids]
    print("OIDs: " + str(oids))
    iterator = getCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData("public", mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget(transportAddr=(ip_address, 161), timeout=10, retries=0),
        ContextData(),
        *oids,
    )

    error_indication, error_status, error_index, variable_bindings = next(iterator)

    ...
```

This seems to work for when the `oids` list is only one or two elements, but it times out for the full list of 16 OIDs for the 16 outlets. And it times out even if I wait like 5 seconds. So I'm not sure what's going on.

I realize there's also a `bulkCmd`, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it, as SNMP is new to me and quite arcane.

---

**Summary**: I have the list of OIDs:

```py
ids = [".1.3.6.1.4.1.3808.1.1.3.3.5.1.1.4.{}".format(outlet) for outlet in range(1, 17)]
```

I am looking for the fastest way to query these such that the response time is well-below a second for the state of all 16 outlets. Ideally the solution uses the `pysnmp` package, but I am open to others as long as they are cross-platform and require no external system dependencies.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an SNMP library (PySNMP or another), as UDP packets have a size limit and the SNMP agent might dislike large packets too. So when you said "I am looking for the fastest way to query these", you'd better know things have constraints.

Comment: SNMP can't bulk query 16 OIDs? Over a second for 16 individual queries is expected? The values being returned are a single integer, so 16 integers in total. So is it the send that's timing out?